# How can I get my encrypt/decrypt files to read from each other?

Tags: java, encryption

I will try and word this without any confusion, but I'm confused so it will be tricky.

I have made a "one off" encrypting program (increment or decrement the chars).Right now, when I enter a random file from the same folder as my program to be encrypted or decrypted, the program does so, and the newly encrypted/decrypted file is sent to either the "Encrypted" or "Decrypted" file with no issues.

My problem is that when I try to pull from the recently "Decrypted" file and encrypt it to turn it back to normal(or vice versa), I get nothing. The data that I had sent to either one of those folders is gone, and I'm not sure why. Sorry if that doesn't make any sense.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Encryptor
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  PrintWriter fileOutE;//Content going to "Encrypted" file
  PrintWriter fileOutD;//Content goint to "Decrypted" file

  String fileName = "";//Name of file user wants to encrypt/decrypt
  String encryptOrDecrypt = "";//eOrc stands for "Encrypt or Decrypt"
  String line = "";
  char ch = ' ';

  try
  {
     //Ask user for file to be encrypted or decrypted
     System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file: ");
     fileName = in.nextLine();

     //Ask user if they want to encrypt or decrypt file
     System.out.println("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt?: ");
     encryptOrDecrypt = in.nextLine();

     File f = new File (fileName);
     Scanner fileIn = new Scanner (f);
     fileOutE = new PrintWriter ("Encrypted.txt");//File for encrypted text
     fileOutD = new PrintWriter ("Decrypted.txt");//File for decrypted text

     if(encryptOrDecrypt.equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt"))
     {
        while(fileIn.hasNextLine())
        {
           line = fileIn.nextLine();

           for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
           {
              ch = line.charAt(i);

              if(Character.isLetter(ch))
              {
                 ch++;
              }

              fileOutE.print(ch);
           }

        }

           fileOutE.close();
           System.out.println("File has been sent to Encrypted.txt");
     }
     if(encryptOrDecrypt.equalsIgnoreCase("decrypt"))
     {
        while(fileIn.hasNextLine())
        {
           line = fileIn.nextLine();

           for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
           {
              ch = line.charAt(i);

              if(Character.isLetter(ch))
              {
                 ch--;
              }

              fileOutD.print(ch);
           }
        }

           fileOutD.close();
           System.out.println("File has been sent to Decrypted.txt");
     }  
   }//end try
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     System.out.println("Got an error");
   }//end catch

}//end main


}//end class
```

Comment: (1) Have you checked if the encrypted/decrypted file is written and contains expected content (e.g. using a hex viewer)? (2) Can it happen that `fileName` is equal to `Encrypted.txt` or `Decrypted.txt`?

Comment: 1-Yes, I can go into the decrypted/encrypted file and see that the program is working correctly(I have only opened the file in like notepad to see that it is working) I'm not sure what a hex view is(am a newbie).2- Yes, actually, the problem is when I try to decrypt/encrypt from the "Decrypted" file, so the fileName would actually equal the Decrypted.txt or Encrypted.txt. How can I fix that?

Comment: Short for hexadecimal viewer (showing file contents as hexadecimal encoded bytes).

Comment: `PrintWriter` deletes any content when opening a file so it can't be read at the same time. The `java.io.File` class provides several methods to help, like `createTempFile`, `renameTo` and `delete`.

Comment: Okay, I will give those a try. Thanks.